# bs_embed_popover with shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm having problems using the popover from `bsplus` with `shinydashboard` since the text is not shown, and it is behind the title panel.

```
library(shiny)
library(bsplus)
library(htmltools)
library(shinydashboard)

# UI
ui <-   
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Title"),
    dashboardSidebar(
      use_bs_popover(),
        selectInput(
          inputId = "letter",
          label = "Label with popover help",
          choices = c("a", "b", "c")
        ) %>%
        shinyInput_label_embed(
          shiny_iconlink() %>%
            bs_embed_popover(
              title = "Letter", content = "Choose a favorite", placement ="right"
            )
        )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
    )
)

# Server
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {    
})

# Run the applicationenter image description here
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, the text is displayed in white (you can try to highlight the text content, it will reveal itself). So it's not hidden, and you can fix that using CSS:

```
.popover-title {color:black;}
.popover-content {color:black;}
```

The second problem is related to the fact that the popover is showing under the navbar, because of each element's `z-index`. The problem is that the popover is nested in the sidebar which has a `z-index` with a numeric value, so even though the popover has a `z-index` greater than the `z-index` of the header, it will remain under the header. To make it work, you just need to set the `z-index` of the sidebar to `auto`:

```
.main-sidebar {z-index:auto}
```

All in all, you could use the following lines to make your shiny app working as desired:

```
dashboardBody(tags$style(HTML('.popover-title {color:black;}
                               .popover-content {color:black;}
                               .main-sidebar {z-index:auto;}'))
)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same with out shinydashboard,using fluidpage() and it's working perfectly okay.
I have tried the same with ShinyBS library using bsPopover and bsButton function.
It might solve your purpose.
Here is code.

```
library(shiny)
library(bsplus)
library(htmltools)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput(
      inputId = "letter",
      label = "Label with popover help",
      choices = c("a", "b", "c")
    )%>%shinyInput_label_embed(
      shiny_iconlink() %>%
        bs_embed_popover(title = "Number", content = "Demo Description", placement ="left")
    ),
    use_bs_popover(),
    selectInput(
      inputId = "letter",
      label = h5("Label with popover help ",
                 tags$style(type = "text/css", "#q1 {float: right;}"),
                 bsButton("q1", label = "", icon = icon("question"), style = "info", size = "extra-small")),
      choices = c("a", "b", "c")),
    bsPopover(id = "q1", title = "Demo data",
              content = paste0("Demo Description "
              ),
              placement = "right", 
              trigger = "focus", 
              options = list(container = "body")
    )
      ),
    dashboardBody()
  )

  server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  })

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Output is:
[image]

Please check if it solves your purpose.